# Конфликт плагинов WordPress/WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Пропали некоторые страницы на WordPress/Elementor. Начал перебирать плагины, оказался конфликт с WooСommerce и Rank Math SEO. Если Rank Math SEO можно заменить, то WooСommerce не получится. Нужно решать проблему.

Когда WooСommerce включен, отображается Главная страница и, собcтвенно, сам Магазин, но нельзя купить товар, потому что не работает страница Корзина. На пустых странцах пишет "Nothing Found
Ready to publish your first post? Get started here." Выключаю плагин WooCommerce, все страницы WordPress работают, ну а магазин, естественно, нет. Может, кто сталкивался?